# Load and store CPU registers in application context

Tags: stm32, cpu, cortex-m3

I just recently started working with a bare STM32F103C8T6 (an ARM Cortex M3) and ran into some difficulties.

I have set up a `SysTick_Handler` to switch the current context of the application. The handler invokes a `PendSV_Handler` in which I want to save the registers of the CPU to a datastructure. This is the simplified code:

```
typedef struct Registers {
    int r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, r12;
    int sp, lr, pc, xPSR;
} Registers;

void PendSV_Handler()
{
    Registers reg;

    register int r0 asm("r0");
    reg.r0 = r0;
    /* and so on with all other registers */
}
```

However while testing the inline asm I ran across an issue. I adapted my handler like this:

```
void PendSV_Handler()
{
    asm volatile(
      "movw r0 100"  // This should store the integer 100 in register r0
    );

    register int temp asm("r0");  // This should store the value in
                                  // register r0 into temp

    toggleLED();     // Toggles an LED to visualise the behavior
    delay_ms(temp);  // Delays the execution by [temp] ms, known to work
    toggleLED();
}
```

Now the problem is that the LED to be toggled only switches on once and then stays stuck. Also in the `SysTick_Handler` another LED is toggled with SysTick-frequency, which also stops toggling after the first `PendSV` call. I know that they have the same priority, which is why I conclude, that the Tick-LED is stuck, because the delay is way too long and this lets me conclude, that the value from the register is not stored correctly. Did I miss out on how to store data from CPU registers or is there another flaw in my conclusions?

Comment: 100 ms is a very short time.

Comment: You may want to show toggleLED(). Are you using any optimizations? (ie: did you forget to assign an LED state variable as "volatile" or possibly as "static" if declared within the function?)

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Not a random value, doesn't the assignment of the value 100 work how I thought it would (i.e. being stored in register r0)?

Comment: @Tut The problem lies not within the toggleLED function. I am able to see it if I manually enter 100 as an argument. The whole program is much more complicated, but I am sure it is the asm part, that doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: Have you tried *disassembling* the compiled code? (Try the -S compiler option if gcc)

Comment: related: [Retrieving return address of an exception on ARM Cortex M0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618440/retrieving-return-address-of-an-exception-on-arm-cortex-m0).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are aware the logic already stores the state of the machine during an event/interrupt. If you want to use this to task switch you need to remove/re-build the stack to account for the switch. You may want to pull that information and save it for the switch back sure.

Take a look at [Atomthreads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems) or [FreeRTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRTOS) or others to see how to do a complete task switch in a Cortex-M (it is not like other processors where you take control of the registers and change the return address. For starters, the "return address" in LR from an event/interrupt is not a valid address -- ["Cortex-M3 Devices Generic User Guide: Exception entry and return"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html)).

Comment: I know that the Cortex-family stores r0-r4 plus some other registers on the stack, so I have to store the others like this. I also know, that I have to pop said registers from the stack and push others to be loaded by the exception return. Thank you for the Wikipedia link, I found one to have a really good documentation.

Answer (score 2):

> in the SysTick_Handler another LED is toggled with SysTick-frequency,
>   which also stops toggling after the first PendSV call. I know that
>   they have the same priority

If `SysTick` and `PendSV` have the same priority, then `SysTick_Handler` will not be invoked again until `PendSV_Handler` returns. That's a problem because `delay_ms()` usually depends on `SysTick_Handler` updating a counter. That will never happen, therefore your program will hang there.

Using `delay_ms()` in an interrupt handler is a bad idea, but if you'd like to have it there for testing purposes, then make sure that `SysTick_Handler` has higher priority than any interrupt using `delay_ms()`. (Or modify `delay_ms()` to use a hardware timer.)

Comment: The delay method is not using timers, but what you mentioned is what I concluded. As the PendSV takes longer than until the next SysTick interrupt is due, the SysTick_Handler is not invoked.